# How to stop processes using a particular port programatically

Tags: php, linux, tcp, process, port

I have a process running on a port in my Linux machine. What I want to do is to check continuously if the port is OK or not. The port is a TCP port that receives data from another Linux box , but when there is access of data it gets crashed and gets stuck on:

```
"Address already in use" message
```

I want to check if it does crash and stop the process using that port so that I can free the port and restart the process. I need to do this using php or bash scripts.

Comment: I'd think youd be better of with an cronjob

Comment: @DonSeba that cronjob has to have a script behind it? Right?

Comment: you could do a try{ open tcp port } catch (Exception $e) { already in use }

Comment: That's something I'd rather see solved by a competent admin over at http://serverfault.com/ than by an ad-hoc developer solution ;-)

Comment: You have a coding problem in the server. Find and fix that, don't apply bandaids. All the 'address in use' conditions should only occur at startup of a server. You are probably closing and reopening the listening socket instead of just leaving it open.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some googling i came at [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/). This tool can be installed on a server and can monitor the programs you choose and start them if they are not running OR restart them if the are not responding accordingly ...

from the site :

> if sendmail is not running, Monit can start sendmail again automatically or if apache is using too much resources (e.g. if a DoS attack is in progress) Monit can stop or restart apache and send you an alert message.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
>
> sudo fuser -k 443/tcp

Specifically to answer the question, while this method is just a patch for a messy server organization.

This said, as i guess it should be fixed 4 years later.